# Gulp convert directory of files and their contents to a JavaScript file

Tags: javascript, gulp

I would like to be able to setup my Gulp build system to do the following: scan a directory of files and store each file's contents as the value in a JavaScript object.

For example, if I have the following directory structure:

```
templates/
  a.html
  b.html
  c/
    x.html
```

The following JavaScript will be generated:

```
templates["a.html"] = "<Contents of templates/a.html>";
templates["b.html"] = "<Contents of templates/a.html>";
templates["c/x.html"] = "<Contents of templates/c/x.html>";
```

Does anyone know of a Gulp plugin that will do this?

Answer (score 0):

May be this will help you: [gulp-concat-util](https://github.com/mgcrea/gulp-concat-util).

Usage:

```
var concat = require('gulp-concat-util');

gulp.task('concat:dist', function() {
  gulp.src('scripts/{,*/}*.js')
    .pipe(concat('combined.js')
    .pipe(concat.header('templates["<%= file.path %>"] ='))
    .pipe(concat.footer(';\n'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});
```